# Correct way to push a view with actionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am an new Android developer so I prefer ask about the correct way so solve my problem.

I have a FragmentActivity and multiple fragments, one of my fragment is compose of button supposed to show new view like a push view in a navigation controler on iOS.

I tried to create new activity and display them with an Intent, but the actionBar disseapeared.

**So what am I suppose to create to work with the actionBar and keep my action bar ?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer myself since I find the solution, maybe it will help.
I will compare to iOS.

If you are working with an actionBar possessing fragment, and you want to open a new view there is 2 different way.

If you want to add a new view over the actionBar and all other the element, create a new Activity and use Intent. 
This method is like modal view on iOS

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

If you want to add a new view within the ActionBar, create a new Fragment and use this code :

```
    Fragment newFragment = new MyNewFragmentClass();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.my_current_layout, newFragment);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
```