# navigate from ListView item to fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to navigate from my ListView Item to a fragment. Fragment and ListView are both part of a TabsAdapter.

I ve tried this:

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{

    // Set up different intents based on the item clicked: 
    switch (position)
    {
    case 0:  
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(l.getContext(), Fragment_2.class);     
        startActivityForResult(newActivity, 0);
        break;

    }

}
```

and this

```
    case 0:  
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment_2.class);     
    startActivityForResult(newActivity, 0);
    break;
```

Both result in a shutdown of my app in the emulator after choosing the item on position 0.

Thank you,
Christian

Comment: Fragment is not an Activity. For displaying frgament yuo should use FrgmentManager

Comment: You should use a Fragment manager example: `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();` Is your list view part of a fragment or an Activity?

Comment: you can't startactivity on a fragment.

Comment: My listview is part of a fragment, I also asumed that my goal-fragment is not to handle as a activity but I also received the same error aiming at the main activity...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your new fragment appear like your other fragment I recommend this method :

```
Fragment newFragment = new MyNewFragmentClass();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.my_current_layout, newFragment);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

I had the same issue myself : [New fragment in actionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244494/correct-way-to-push-a-view-with-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

As the list view is also a part of your fragment, you can do in following way:

**1**. Listen to Item Click Listener of List in Fragment (as I think, you have already done) . But instead of simply creating an Activity, pass an Bundle message to pass the Tab position.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
     switch (position) {
         case 0:  
           Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Fragment_2.class); 
           newActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
           newActivityIntent.putExtra("tabToStart", "2"); //Pass the desired tab no. 
           startActivity(fragmentIntent);
           break;
      }
}
```

**2**. In  `Oncreate()` method of the Parent Activity (which holds the Fragment 1 and Fragment2) , you have to get the bundle message using `getIntent()`, and change the Tab position accordingly.

```
Intent intLoc = getIntent();
String loc = intLoc.getStringExtra("tabToStart");
if (loc.equals("2")) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
}
```

Kindly let me know if further details are required.